# Tor LFS and TAILS

Tags: tails

Hope this isn't stupid but I've thought about this on and off for a while: Does it make sense to build a Linux From Scratch (or BLFS) project (hardened?) using the TAILS component list as the model? The idea being to launch Tor from the best possible foundation? This will increase user familiarity with the components which should improve security as well. Someone who is familiar with this should be able to explain why this might be a weaker or stronger environment for launching Tor.

Comment: I'm making my own Linux distro with Tor inside btw, so contact me if you're eager to test it

Answer (score 1):

You might want to read [Why is Tails based on Debian and not on another distribution?](https://tails.boum.org/support/faq/index.en.html#index2h2) and [Why isn't Tails based on Ubuntu?](https://tails.boum.org/support/faq/index.en.html#index3h2)

Please also have a look at the number of [projects which are now discontinued](https://tails.boum.org/about/index.en.html#index7h1) because maintainability had not been thought from the beginning. What is the best foundation for running Tor? A super-tweaked set of software that is several months old and contains known security holes or something closer to a common ground but refreshed every six weeks?